# Canon MG3250 Printer Colours

Tags: printing, canon

I have just purchased a Canon MG3250 printer for it's wireless functionality. Unfortunately when printing from Ubuntu the colour profile is way out.
Can anyone guide me through calibrating this at all? I'm not after photographic or publishing standards of colour accuracy, just want greens to be green, reds to be red not brown etc. - just good enough for home office use.

I have tried the drivers listed elsewhere on this forum, and they perform just the same as just adding the printer from within the OS without the proprietary drivers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems to print OK from OSX and Windows. If anybody can offer any advice I'd appreciate it as it's very frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

On 14.04 64 bit  I did this to fix the colour

1) Download the driver from Canon

http://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg3250.aspx?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:14-994521&os=Linux%20%2864-bit%29&language=EN

Extract the files to somewhere

2) Fix a dependency by installing an old library version

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/amd64/libtiff4/download

(this was not a clean system, if your missing something else find that on the packages site too, the latest version you find)

3) Install the appropriate .deb files in the 'packages' folder in the stuff you extracted in step 1, 'common' then 'mg3200series'

4) Install or change the printer driver or 'make and model' and look for "Canon MG3200 series Ver.3.80" the broken one lacks the version info.

Once updated the prints were excellent.